# Sturm-Liouville problem $y'' + q(x)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be a nontrivial solution of Sturm-Liouville problem $$y'' + q(x)y = 0$$
with $q(x) > 0$.

If $\int_0^\infty q(x)dx = \infty$ then $y$ have a infinity positive roots.

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y$ has no zeroes on $[x_0,\infty)$. We may assume without loss of generality that $y(x)>0$ for $x\ge x_0$. Then $y$ is concave on $[x_0,\infty)$. If $y'(x)<0$ for some $x\ge x_0$ then $y$ must vanish at some point, so that $y'(x)\ge0$ for $x\ge x_0$. On the other hand
$$
0=\int_{x_0}^xy''(t)\,dt+\int_{x_0}^xq(t)\,y(t)\,dt\ge y'(x)-y'(x_0)+y(x_0)\int_{x_0}^xq(t)\,dt,
$$
leading to a contradiction.